# Microsoft Graph Explorer Check if user is mailenabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

i try to find a query to check which AAD users are mail enabled.
I think with PowerShell checking the users mailbox will work (attribute ismailenabled), but i cant find something equal in the Microsoft Graph documentation.

Any ideas how i can get a list of mailenabled users in graph explorer?

BR
Thomas

Comment: Could you provide the powershell command that you used to check `mailenabled`?

Comment: im using exchange online PowerShell and this cmdlet: "Get-Recipient" If the mailbox is not enabled the output is: Recipienttype = Mailuser

Answer (score 1):

There is no `mailenabled` property for user in the Microsoft Graph API. For the all properties of user, please read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user).

Comment: thought so as i have to check also with PowerShell the mailbox. May i can check the mailboxes also with graph?

Comment: Yes, you had better check it with Powershell, I'm not sure it can work.

Comment: i found following reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings looks like this is possible to get at least the mailboxsettings: But, when trying this query i receive an error that i have not enough privileges: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/mailboxSettings - however, the right permissions as referenced in this article are granted

Comment: Facing the same issue even when querying the `/me/mailboxSettings` from the Graph API explorer with the right permissions granted and keep getting a 401 with `"code": "UnknownError"`. Any info on how to actually enable mail for an AAD user?

Comment: You need to request the `MailboxSettings.Read` in order to read the `mailboxSettings` object.

Comment: You can use mailboxsettings to check the user mailenabled status one by one.

Comment: And the `mailboxsettings` just returns result for  archiveFolder, language, automaticRepliesSetting, timeZone, and workingHours. There is no result for the mailenable status. I think there will be no help for you in the Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Comment: @SunnySun did you find any way to identify whether a user has UserMailBox or MailUser using Graph API?